# How to show the git remote origin on the status bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to know if there's a way to show the current git origin on the status bar.

It's really hard when working on a multi-project workspace, to know what's the current focused repository that shows on the status bar of VS Code editor.

[image]

Comment: You want it to show something like `origin/master` (same as `git branch -r`) or something like `origin git@github.com:project/myrepo.git` (same as `git remote -v`) ?

Comment: I would like more the second option: `origin git@github.com:project/myrepo.git`